# ngx-infinite-scroll: how do you set the [horizontal] value based on the width of the parent?

Tags: angular

I am trying to set horizontal boolean based on the width of the parent but it looks like, because the variable is set inside ngAfterViewInit, the inifinite scroll directive is not accepting the defined boolean value; Because the resulting behavior in the GUI shows it is always interpreting it as falsy

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to render the `scrollContainer` after the parent has been inizialized, that way you know for sure that the value has already been set.

Comment: Horizontal property supposed to handle the scroll to listen for horizontal events, so if you have horizontal scrollbars you can just set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the following npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll

I just had a look at the source code and I found the issue:

https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll/blob/master/projects/ngx-infinite-scroll/src/lib/ngx-infinite-scroll.directive.ts

Basically, they are using the 'isHorizontal' input only in the **ngOnInit()** of the directive, and in the **ngOnChanges** they are making some actions only if one of the following properties is changed: **infiniteScrollContainer, infiniteScrollDisabled, infiniteScrollDistance**.

The issue is that you are getting the boolean value for your isHorizontal property in the ngAfterViewInit() of your component but previously you already sent undefined  (converted to false) to the infinite scroll directive and as we checked, the directive will not accept any additional change for this input.

**Basically we have 2 possible solutions here:**

1. Wrap the div with the infinite scroll directive in a *ngIf to ensure that the infinite scroll directive will be instantiated only if you set a true/false value to the isHorizontal property

or

2. After you set the isHorizontal boolean, change again one of theses inputs with the same value infiniteScrollContainer, infiniteScrollDisabled, infiniteScrollDistance (since we saw that they are handling only the changes related to these inputs)